# 3 Year Old Primer Paint On Walls

Tags: painting, primer

I purchased a condo 3 years ago, the condo was painted with white primer, and for a number of reasons I never painted the walls.

If I now want to paint the walls, should I apply a new coat of primer before painting, or should the current coat be alright?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would re-prime.  3 years is a long time, and your expectation is that this paint job will last even longer.  It's possible that it would be fine without, but if it's not, you'll regret the decision.  You could always use a primer + paint combo as long as you're not switching between oil and latex.

Answer (score 0):

No reason to reapply primer just purchase  a paint of ur color choice and get one with a primer with it if ur worried. I've been in the drywall and painting business for over 20+ years and I would be happy to coming into a house that has a primer or white/flat white walls  id be happy. Id go ahead and paint it..

Comment: This is actually what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

Paint manufacturers will tell you primers must be finish coAted within 30 days for proper adhesion.  Yes commercial painters in my area have better visual results if they apply two primer coats and then walk away.  This is both ignorant and unethical.